# Configure SOLR to combine words that are misspelled with excess white space

Tags: solr, synonym

I'm new the SOLR configuration and all, so I might not be given enough info for you to help me. Please feel free to leave comment that ask for more info.

Basically, when a user search for "sun glasses" my search is not returning the result with the word "sunglasses" because the search word get parsed into "sun" and "glasses".

Exactly where should I configure my SOLR to understand that "sun glasses" means "sunglasses"

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically, I found out my answer on my own. So here is the answer:

http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2013/10/27/why-is-multi-term-synonyms-so-hard-in-solr/

This solution works for my case.